# What are good values to assume for correlation and sphericity when estimating sample size for a within-subjects design

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, sample-size, statistical-power, sphericity

I am planning a within-subjects study with four different conditions and I am using [G*Power](http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/aap/projects/gpower/) to calculate my needed sample size. Not being intimately acquainted with the intricacies of statistics in general (and repeated measures ANOVA in particular) what are some good assumptions for the *correlation among repeated measures* and *nonsphericity correction* values? What can I base these values on rather than guesswork?